# List friends that share no mutual guilds, discord.py rewrite

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've tried the code below, but I get this error. I clearly do not have the correct attribute, but I cannot find it in the documentation.

`AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'mutual_guilds`

```
@bot.command()
async def C(ctx):
    for user in bot.user.friends:
        if user.mutual_guilds == None:
            print ("Friend: " + user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mutual_guilds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Profile.mutual_guilds) is a property of a `User`s `Profile`

```
@bot.command()
async def C(ctx):
    for user in bot.user.friends:
        profile = await user.profile()
        if not profile.mutual_guilds:
            print ("Friend: " + user.name+"#"+user.discriminator)
```